# does exist more convenient manner to create blank spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot

Although create a blank web project or non-web project online(https://start.spring.io/) is easy, you still have to access web, unzip, import to IDE. So does still exist more convenient manner to create blank spring boot project? e.g. in shell command.

Comment: You know that `STS` has a new project wizzard which connects to start.spring.io automatically ?

Comment: which IDE are you using? IntelliJ IDEA provides a wizard for Spring Initializr (start.spring.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[STS](http://spring.io/tools) (which basically is Eclipse) contains a wizzard which talks to start.spring.io. You should be able to install the same plugins into an existing Eclipse using the update site shown there: http://spring.io/tools/sts/all or through market place.

This is what is shown when you do `Ctrl+N` in your IDE:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you and +1 for this, but I am getting a downstream error after doing this.  Are you willing to comment on the downstream error?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056364/spring-boot-sample-throws-mojoexecutionexception-in-eclipse

Comment: Would it help if I re-framed the other question?  Or added any specific information?  I would like to make it a better question that is easier for people to answer.

Comment: @CodeMed I would be willing to comment but have no idea what is going wrong ;-)