# Spring Boot sample throws MojoExecutionException in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am studying spring security and AngularJS using [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/).  Part One of the tutorial specifies very specific changes to the `pom.xml`. But when I add those `pom.xml` changes, an error results.

In eclipse, the error is a compilation error message as follows:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:  ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-maven-plugin:1.7.6:run (execution: default, phase: generate-resources)
```

which appears at the following line in `pom.xml`:

```
    <execution>  <!-- this line throws the compilation error in eclipse -->
          <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
```

When I try to bypass eclipse by running `mvn spring-boot:run` on the CentOS terminal, the following stack trace results:

```
[root@localhost demo]# mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] lots of INFO lines
[INFO] folder: /home/user/workspace_angular/demo/target/generated-resources/static/css
[INFO] processing group: angular-bootstrap.css
[WARNING] Less warnings are:
[WARNING] 10:1 Cannot link source map. Css result location is not know and could not be deduced from input less source..
[INFO] file size: angular-bootstrap.css -> 131752 bytes
[INFO] lots more INFO lines
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ demo ---
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.0.RELEASE)
2015-12-02 16:40:08.685  INFO 10511 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Starting DemoApplication on localhost.localdomain with PID 10511 (/home/user/workspace_angular/demo/target/classes started by root in /home/user/workspace_angular/demo)
2015-12-02 16:40:08.687  INFO 10511 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : No profiles are active
2015-12-02 16:40:08.886  INFO 10511 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4617731: startup date [Wed Dec 02 16:40:08 PST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-12-02 16:40:10.390  INFO 10511 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-12-02 16:40:11.637  INFO 10511 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2015-12-02 16:40:11.666  INFO 10511 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-12-02 16:40:11.667  INFO 10511 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
2015-12-02 16:40:11.932  INFO 10511 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-12-02 16:40:11.932  INFO 10511 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3046 ms
2015-12-02 16:40:12.524  INFO 10511 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-12-02 16:40:12.527  INFO 10511 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-02 16:40:12.528  INFO 10511 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-02 16:40:12.528  INFO 10511 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-02 16:40:12.528  INFO 10511 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-02 16:40:13.061  INFO 10511 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4617731: startup date [Wed Dec 02 16:40:08 PST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-12-02 16:40:13.265  INFO 10511 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/resource]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> com.example.DemoApplication.home()
2015-12-02 16:40:13.267  INFO 10511 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-12-02 16:40:13.268  INFO 10511 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-12-02 16:40:13.296  INFO 10511 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.c.a.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter      : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2015-12-02 16:40:13.303  INFO 10511 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2015-12-02 16:40:13.348  INFO 10511 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-12-02 16:40:13.348  INFO 10511 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-12-02 16:40:13.485  INFO 10511 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-12-02 16:40:13.826  INFO 10511 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-12-02 16:40:13.964 ERROR 10511 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:237) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:290) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:29) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:467) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
2015-12-02 16:40:13.966 ERROR 10511 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:237) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:290) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:29) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:467) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    ... 20 common frames omitted    
2015-12-02 16:40:13.989  INFO 10511 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2015-12-02 16:40:14.004  INFO 10511 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath:  
[file:/home/user/workspace_angular/demo/target/classes/, 
many other files in classpath omitted here on SO for brevity  
....
file:/root/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar]
2015-12-02 16:40:14.005 ERROR 10511 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:290) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:29) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:467) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:467)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException:     Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:290)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101)
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:29)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159)
    ... 16 more
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.112 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-02T16:40:14-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 55M/156M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project demo: An exception occured while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container: Tomcat connector in failed state -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**Note there is an `address already in use` error mixed in the above stack trace.  At first, I thought the error might be due to a port 8080 conflict when restarting the program, but the problem persists even when I run `shutdown.sh` and `startup.sh` to restart tomcat.**  Also, note that the message at the end of the stack trace indicates that a plugin within pom.xml might be causing the problem, which you can verify [by clicking on this link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException).

The complete code in the `pom.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
          <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
        </resource>
      </resources>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <!-- Serves *only* to filter the wro.xml so it can get an absolute path for the project -->
              <id>copy-resources</id>
              <phase>validate</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/wro</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                  <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/wro</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                  </resource>
                </resources>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.6</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>generate-resources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
           <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
            <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/css</cssDestinationFolder>
            <jsDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/js</jsDestinationFolder>
            <wroFile>${project.build.directory}/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
            <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
            <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/wro</contextFolder>
          </configuration>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
              <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
              <version>2.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
              <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
              <version>1.3.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
              <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
              <version>3.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I created the project in eclipse with the Spring Tool Suite add ons by selecting `File > New > Project... > Spring > Spring Starter Project` with only the default parameters, and then following the instructions in the above-linked tutorial explicitly.

The instructions in the tutorial worked until I added the changes to `pom.xml` shown above and articulated in part one of the tutorial.

**So what do I have to do to get the program to compile?**

Comment: Do not do shutdown.sh and startup.sh to restart tomcat. Just make sure your Tomcat in CentOS is shutdown and  try executing `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: @localhost999 I rebooted the machine and am able to run the program now by typing in `mvn spring-boot:run` at the CentOS terminal.  This leaves that terminal window in the semi-frozen state indicating that a command it has been given is still running.  How do I terminate and restart the spring boot app in this state?  Do I just `Ctrl-C` and then retype `mvn spring-boot:run` again when I want to run a recompiled program?  This approach bypasses eclipse altogether.

Comment: I know this is late, but it may help other people out too. Try running `mvn clean install spring-boot:run` this will recompile your program and run your spring boot app

Answer (score 2):

When you execute `mvn spring-boot:run` it has its own embedded Tomcat, so it does not need separated Tomcat instance to run, thus you have conflict between this two Tomcat.

You have to just run: `shutdown.sh` and left it this way and try again.

Comment: This does not resolve the problem.  However, rebooting the computer does enable the app to run again.  But the problem resurfaces again the second time I try to recompile and launch the problem, and is again resolved by rebooting the computer.

Comment: Then your problem is with IDE or the utility from where run your command, what is happening is that, when you run the app first time, it stays turned on. Let me know which IDE you use, or if terminal run `ps aux` and search for tomcat, like `ps aux | grep tomcat`, if you find it you can kill it with process number like `kill 32423` (32423 is an example)

Comment: I use eclipse. I will try PS aux when I am back at my PC. It is the middle of the night here.

Comment: Also take a look at this for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432651/terminating-mvn-spring-bootrun-doesnt-stop-tomcat